# Grails Ajax table - how to implement?

Tags: ajax, grails

I've input:

```
<g:form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom" method="post"
        controller="simple" action="addEntry">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Put your data HERE"
             class="form-control" name="InputData" id="top-search">
   </div>
</g:form>
```

And table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="editable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <g:render template="/shared/entry" var="entry"
                  collection="${entries}" />
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Controller:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])
class SimpleController {

def springSecurityService
def user

def index() {

    user =  springSecurityService.principal.username
    def entries = Entry.findAllByCreatedBy(user)
    [entries: entries]
}


def addEntry(){

        def entries = Entry.findAllByCreatedBy(user)
        render(entries: entries)
    }
}
```

I just want to dynamically update the table with data from input string.
What is the best way? 
Will be grateful for examples/solutions

Comment: Is there I reason I can't have that yummy bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the table using AJAX with Grail's formRemote tag.

### Input form

```
<g:formRemote 
    name="entryForm" 
    url="[controller: 'entry', action: 'add']"
    update="entry">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</g:formRemote>
```

### HTML table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="entry">
        <g:render
            template="/entry/entry" 
            var="entry"
            collection="${entries}" />
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Entry template

```
<tr>
    <td>${entry.name}</td>
    <td>${entry.dateCreated}</td>
</tr>
```

### Controller

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

class EntryController {

    def index() {
        [entries: Entry.list(readOnly: true)]
    }

    @Transactional
    def add(String name) {
        def entry = new Entry(name: name).save()

        render(template: '/entry/entry', collection: Entry.list(), var: 'entry')
    }
}
```

### How it works

When the **add** button is pressed the *add* controller method is called. The controller method creates the domain instance and renders the *_entry.gsp* template. But instead of refreshing the browser page, the template is rendered to an AJAX response. On the client side, the rendered template is inserted into the DOM inside of the *tbody* element with id *entry*, as defined in the *formRemote* tag by the *update* attribute.

Note that with this approach all of the entries are re-rendered, not just the new one. Rendering only the new one is a bit trickier.

### Resources

- [Complete source code for my answer](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/grails-ajax-table-example/overview)
- [Grails AJAX](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you direction ( you are not showing any of your controller and js code.):

---

1. Create an action your controller ( the responsible controller) that will render the template `/shared/entry` by passing `entries` collection.
2. On submit of the form make ajax call to the action defined above, then replace the `tbody` html by the returned view fragment(template).

Comment: Hi, I've added controller, could you explain in basic, how and where I should make ajax call and what js code needed? Sry for noob question..