# Grails 3.0 Ajax invokes controller's method but does not render view

Tags: ajax, grails

The view displays list of users in a table. One user (row) is selected by clicking the mouse. The JavaScript gets the user's info and Ajax(es) or invokes the controller. The Controller saves data to a session and renders a view. Controller stores data in a session but never renders the view. No error is logged. 
Any help is appreciated. I have spent almost a week and got nowhere.
Below are the view and controller excerpts.

```
function getRowDataFromTable(_row) { //get data of selected row
    /*input argument _row is the row number starting at 0 |   columns are fixed (5 cols) start at 1
     r0c1 r0c2 r0c3 r0c4 r0c5    r1c1 r1c2 r1c3 r1c4 r1c5  ........   rNc1 rNc2 rNc3 rNc4 rNc5*/

    var _id=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c1").innerHTML;
    var  _firtsname=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c2").innerHTML;
    var  _lastname=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c3").innerHTML;
    var _kname=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c4").innerHTML;
    var _email=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c5").innerHTML;
    var _govtemp=document.getElementById("r"+_row+"c6").innerHTML;
    console.log("userid: " + _id);
    var data = {};    data.userid=_id;      data.firstname=varToString(_firtsname);     data.lastname=varToString(_lastname);//JS object
    console.log("data = {}: " + data.userid + " : " + data.firstname + " : " + data.lastname + " : ");

    invokeController(data);  
}

function invokeController(data){ 
    $.ajax({
        url:'${g.createLink( controller:'SummaryOfProjectWithPL', action:'summarize_withPL')}',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'post', //'get'
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
 }
```

.......

## Controller:

class SummaryOfProjectWithPLController {
    static defaultAction = "summarize_withPL"
    .....
    def summarize_withPL() {

```
    println('..... SummaryOfProjectController.summarize_withPL() [to select/change Project Leader] ')
    def userID_PL=jsonObj.userid; def userFirstName_PL=jsonObj.firstname; def userLastName_PL=jsonObj.lastname
    //update scoped session data by adding these to session
    userID_PL=session.userID_PL; userFirstName_PL=session.userFirstName_PL; userLastName_PL=session.userLastName_PL
    println(' session data ' + session.userID_PL + ' | '+ session.userFirstName_PL + ' | '+ session.userLastName_PL)

    render (view:'/newproject/summaryOfProject.gsp', 
           model: [userFirstName: session.userFirstName, userLastName: session.userLastName, userID: session.userID ,
                   userID_PL: session.userID_PL,  userFirstName_PL: session.userFirstName_PL, userLastName_PL: session.userLastName_PL ])
   }
```

....

Comment: Where is the JavaScript function that handles the ajax response?

Comment: here it is : function invokeController(data){ 
    $.ajax({
        url:'${g.createLink( controller:'SummaryOfProjectWithPL', action:'summarize_withPL')}',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'post', //'get'
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
 }

Comment: That's the function that initiates the Ajax request. I'm asking about the callback for the Ajax response. I don't see one in your example.

Comment: I see my issue now. Thanks, Emmanuel for your question.

Comment: function invokeController(data){ShowUserListForPLChange.getRowData() ; for testing only
        var msg = "eureka";
        $.ajax({
            url: "${g.createLink( controller:'SummaryOfProjectWithPL', action:'summarize_withPL')}",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );   }
        });
    }
Still my view is not rendered... Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting the view to render within the existing page, or is the web browser supposed to navigate to /newproject/summaryOfProject?

Comment: navigate to /newproject/summaryOfProject where the user info is added to it.  Thanks, Emmanuel for your quick response. I use Ajax trying to send data from a table  to a Controller that renders a view.

Comment: You're welcome. One more question: Why are you using Ajax instead of a  form post to submit the data to the controller?

Comment: Summary of project has an option to add people to it. When an Add people button is clicked  it takes to another page where some last name is entered and a table is generated.From that table a row is selected and that user's info is sent to a controller which renders a view.  I used JavaScript to generate a table listing these users since a table is not a Grails out of the box component. I hope I have answered your question. Besides, I want to experiment Ajax in Grails 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using AJAX, the `summaryOfProject.gsp` view is *rendering* to an AJAX response rather than informing the browser to redirect to the page. If your AJAX request is successful, you'll see the HTML rendering of `summaryOfProject.gsp` in the msg variable of your callback handler. As a test, you can write it to the javascript console to confirm.

Basically, what you're trying to achieve doesn't quite fix the AJAX model. What would fit is a process like this:

1. The *Add people* button opens an HTML dialog (such as the one produced by Twitter Bootstrap).
2. In the dialog you do what you're currently doing in the second page.
3. When you receive the AJAX callback, use the data in it to update the existing page.

This means the entire transaction remains on the same page. That's what AJAX is good for. For an example of how to do this in Grails, see [Grails Ajax table - how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240553/grails-ajax-table-how-to-implement)

Comment: Emmanuel, what is the equivalent of formRemote tag  in Grails 3.0. Thanks

Comment: Good question! It looks like it's now gone from grails core. We were warned. It's now the ajax-tags plugin: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/org.grails.plugins%3Aajax-tags/view

Comment: I believe the Maven artifact is `org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1`

Comment: Emmanuel,  regarding "2. In the dialog you do what you're currently doing in the second page"...it means the html dialog has to display an input text box (user last name entry) and a submit button which sends a query to a database back end. Fetched result displays a table of users with the same last name and from the table a selected row with user's info ...Question: Can I do this process with the suggested HTML dialog? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You'll have two AJAX requests: one for the table of users and the one from the original question. So you'll end up with two _placeholders_ in your HTML which you'll fill with the AJAX responses. The table would go within the dialog and the other... wherever it's supposed to go in the main page.

Comment: Emmanuel, I have looked into Bootstrap's modal form but having problem with the implementation. Is there a good example of a GSP with a button when clicked displays a dialog box with input text, submit button and possibly a table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's an example of a modal displayed on a button click. The modal contains a form and a couple of buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: Emmanuel, can you show me a sample where a GSP invokes a Bootstrap Modal form.  Thanks.

Comment: Invoking/showing a modal form is done in JavaScript. There's nothing GSP-specific. It's just the function: $('#myModal').modal('show')

Comment: One more question. Where do the Bootstrap modal form elements reside?  On the same GSP or in a separate GSP or something else? Thanks.

Comment: It needs to end up in the same HTML page. So you can put it in the same GSP page, or in a GSP template which you import into the GSP page. If you plan to use the same modal in different pages, then a template would be the better choice.

Comment: Emmanuel, Thank you for your answers and suggestion. JavaScript, JQuery, AJax, CSS, and Twitter Bootstrap are a big part of my GSP design now. Thanks again and Happy New Year.